# Do I design my device correctly?

Tags: power, usb, atmega328p

I am going to create an **electronic scale** that measures weight (up to 1 kilogram (2.2 pounds)).

For this I will use:

- [Atmega328p](https://static.chipdip.ru/lib/549/DOC001549488.pdf)
- [SSD1306 module](http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/index.php?title=OLED-SSD1306_Module)
- [HX711](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ForceFlex/hx711_english.pdf)
- [load cell](http://qqtrading.com.my/load-cell-1kg-straight-bar-weigh-sensor)

I will charge this using **USB**

For this I will use:

- [TP4056](https://static.chipdip.ru/lib/977/DOC002977110.pdf)  + Li-ion ( 3,7 V; 3400 mAh)
- [step-up DC/DC converter](https://mcustore.ru/store/moduli-pitaniya/preobrazovatel-dc-dc-5v-povyshayushhij-miniatyurnyj/) (input 0.9-5 V and output 5 V (if input>3V: 380-480mA))

I plan to put all this on a printed circuit board and...

Have I designed the power correctly for Atmega328p (0.2mA), HX711 (<1.5mA), SSD1306(15mA), load-cell(1.2 ±0.1mV/V)?

Is it normal to use the [**battery Li-ion**](https://aliexpress.ru/item/32807032859.html?spm=a2g0v.search0302.3.2.679a530fI8RXpG&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_0,searchweb201603_0,ppcSwitch_0&algo_pvid=4680188f-219d-4149-898d-8dee77027a78&algo_expid=4680188f-219d-4149-898d-8dee77027a78-0) ( 3,7 V; 3400 mAh)?

Or maybe you can suggest an alternative!?

I will be grateful for the answer!

Comment: Where is your design?

Comment: @Wesley Lee, First I want to know if I'm using my devices correctly (atmega328, hx711...)?

Comment: That's impossible to say without seeing the design.  This is more of a parts list.  It's equivalent to "How's my table design?  -top  -legs"

Comment: @Cristobol Polychronopolis, Yes, it is parts list.  I have plans to draw a design in the future. At this stage, I wanted to find out whether it is normal to use a Li-ion battery? Have you met any designs similar to this one?

Comment: Scales usually use a 9-V battery, which lasts for years. Why do you think a Li-ion battery will give you any advantage?

Comment: @Ale..chenski, You suggest using a 9 V battery and a step down step-down DC/DC converter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Design seems to be missing, but a few critiques:

- overall BOM (bill of materials) cost seems high given how cheaply I can buy scales
- no accuracy spec. In fact, no spec at all. How accurately will this weigh? Calibration? Drift?
- no mechanical design (particularly important for this application, given the mounting of the load cell)
- battery seems completely wrong. My kitchen scales take normal AA batteries with a life of several years, rather than a phone battery that will go flat in months.
- no controls: how do I turn it on? Tare? Units? (some people may want Imperial units for cooking)
- power saving when not in use: mechanical off switch or something else? Note that the standby usage of a default Arduino is very high

Comment: Control will be carried out using buttons, the display is not just that, these scales will be multifunctional, I just did not write out their functionality.
As for the battery, you can tell how to power this device with AA?

Comment: I'd assume the same boost converter would work, its specs you've quoted are in range.

Comment: AA are designed on average for 800 mAh, this device will not quickly discharge?

Comment: @user10360597, to determine how quickly your design will last on a battery of certain capacity, you need to know your power consumption. Do you have any estimations for this?

Comment: @ Ale..chenski,  If I use a USB and Li ion battery, my balance will support the function (discharge and charge) using USB and TP4056 (only compatible with a Li ion battery). Power consumption 0.2 mA + 1.5 mA + 15mA. I thought this was the best option since the scales will work about 4 hours a day. What do you think about this?